# How to customize thank you mail after subscription using mailchimp?

Tags: wordpress, mailchimp

I am using `mailchimp for WP` plugin for product promotion in ecommerce site (voberhat.com). I configure all the staff and subscription is working perfectly. but when I got return email to confirm subscription there are lot of text which is just like a junk. Here is the mail as a test subscriber to see how my customer see this:
[image]

Here 'Customer' title is looking odd. Again at the bottom there is a mailchimp logo. And the template is not look professional. I searched to modify this things  but failed to navigate where this mail content is. Any idea?

N.B: I am using a list named 'Customer'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change that via the plugin. Login into MailChimp and navigate to 'Lists > Signup forms (Stats dropdown of your list) > Form builder' and select 'Opt-in confirmation email' from 'Forms and response emails'. Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your time. I can customize all except mailchimp logo. Is it possible to remove this logo in free account?

Comment: No, all free versions must include MailChimp logo but you can change its design (predefined) via 'Design it > MonkeyRewards' in the same page itself.